# Can't find certain command settings

Tags: modeling

I have a background with 3D cad, and since a few days I am trying to learn blender.

When you use the extrude and or subdivide command there are of course some setting.
Stetting like use origine of each surface.

Now my problem, most of the time I can't find those settings, that influence the command.

I am trying to follow some tutorials, and sometimes my blender acts like in the tutorial, but also some times it does not. I understand this is because of those setting but I can find them.
What am I doing wrong? :)

And example of a tutorial I try to follow:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2lw9JwTrI8&list=PLNShHVjao84f33iutaehtc_k6pR_hZMKt&index=3&t=0s

Subdivide instead of scaling each surface, I see blender do something different.
Where are those setting hiding ?

Blender 2.8

Comment: are you talking about the Operator box? It appears on the bottom left of your 3D view just after an operation, but disappears as soon as you launch another one. Not sure about your "subdivide instead of scaling" though...

Comment: Thank you
That is probably what I am looking for, I am gonna have a look.

About subdivide, in the tutorial all surface scale inwards, when I try to do this , only the outside of the surface scale , but stay clued together on the inside. 
This must be caused by some setting, but I am having huge issues finding it. :)

Comment: I think I found it :) 

As you said, bottom left a panel appears, I only need to click it to show the options.

One of the setting related to this, individual, when I select this, blender does what I want to do. You saved my day.

Comment: about your second question please tell at what minute of the video you're referring to

Comment: Its all solved, I feel a bit of stupid, but I just had to click the panel so it opens and shows the setting I could not find.

3min 40 he says Make sure individual is selected.
I could not find that setting, but now with your help I could. 

Thank you

Comment: I am still struggling. 

Made a screenshot which should help explain my problem.

https://i.imgur.com/dxQcfEg.png

That panel in the red square, can't I make this appear right away? 
It seems it only appears after I dragged the yellow plus sign.
I don't get the logic behind that, why does this not appear right after I selected the command. ?

Comment: it's the Operator box, it will be there once you've made the operation. Your question is relevant though, I guess there must be a reason but I can't tell   :/

Comment: It seems that clicking in the viewport is the only way, and then you might have to set some values to 0 before proceeding.